# Why loop.run_in_executor still blocks event loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Use following code as an example. The main idea is having one thread running the sync code and submit an async task to the main thread (the event loop).

```py
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
from time import sleep

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
async def a():
    print('a')
    # simulate IO-bound async code
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print('b')

def c():
    print('c')
    x = loop.create_task(a())
    # simulate CPU-bound code
    sleep(1)
    print('d')

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
future = loop.run_in_executor(executor, c)
loop.run_forever()
```

---

I expect to see output of

```
c
a
[wait 0.1 second]
b
[wait 0.9 second]
d
```

but I actually see

```
c
[wait 1 second]
d
a
[wait 0.1 second]
b
```

Based on my understanding the main thread/loop shouldn't block by the run_in_executor future and should start run the async function upon submitted.

Tested on
Python 3.11.5 (main, Aug 24 2023, 15:09:45) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin

Any one can help explain the behavior? Is there any way I can trigger async code from sync code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `create_task` is not thread_safe: Despite no corrupt data taking place, because the sets, dicts and other structures used internally by asyncio are guarded by GIL, the loop does not expect for new things for it to do to show up when it was just awaiting for its solely thread-safe task, which was the `run_in_executor` call.

Using the thread-safe calls provided in asyncio will do the correct things internally. This code works as you expect:

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
from time import sleep, time

_ellapsed_counter = time()
def ellapsed():
    global _ellapsed_counter
    tmp = time() - _ellapsed_counter
    _ellapsed_counter = time()
    return f"[ellapsed {tmp:.02f}s]\n"

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
async def a():
    print(ellapsed(), 'a')
    # simulate IO-bound async code
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print(ellapsed(), 'b')

async def helper():
    loop.create_task(a())

def c():
    print(ellapsed(), 'c')
    x = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(helper(), loop)
    # simulate CPU-bound code
    sleep(1)
    print(ellapsed(), 'd')

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
future = loop.run_in_executor(executor, c)
loop.run_forevever()
```

Comment: That solved my issue. Thank you! Just one more question, seems the functionality of run_coroutine_threadsafe is very similar to asycio.run. So in which case we should use asycio.run? Just when we need better performance for scenarios don't need thread safe?

Comment: No - asyncio.run is quite different - it actually creates a new event loop if there is none yet, does the equivalent of `run_until_complete`, and have some extra niceties for shutting down async generators when its done. And, more important, `asyncio.run` will run in the thread in which it was called, creating a new loop if there is none bound to this  thread.